# Diagnosing connectivity/bandwidth issues in multi-level virtual infrastructure

Tags: virtualbox, connection, bandwidth, cisco-vpn-client, vmware-horizon

### Core Question

How can I both maintain internet connectivity in the L0 Host while also establishing a stable connection in the L2 Client with enough bandwidth to support video conferencing? How can I even diagnose exactly where the problem is?

### Background

I work for a consulting company and I'm using my personal system to do some technical work for an enterprise customer. For privacy/security, the customer has provided a virtual desktop inside their network. To connect to the customer's network, I first had to install Cisco Secure Client (formerly AnyConnect) VPN client. When the Cisco VPN is activated, it completely blocks ALL internet traffic *except* for connecting to the provided virtual desktop, which I access using VMWare Horizon. However, I also need to maintain access to my employer's infrastructure (Slack, email, Drive, etc.) which is blocked when the Cisco VPN is active and which is NOT accessible via the virtual desktop.

To resolve the connectivity issues, I set up my system as pictured below. I installed VirtualBox on my main system and setup a Windows VM client (L1). I installed the Cisco VPN client and VMWare Horizon on L1. This way, when I'm connected to the Cisco VPN on L1, I am able to maintain normal internet access on L0, and only L1 is blocked. I am able to connect to the virtual desktop (L2) from within L1, but:

- It is constantly disconnecting/reconnecting at random intervals, dumping me out of my L2 virtual desktop, and
- The bandwidth in L2 is ***terrible*** and not good enough for video conferencing, screen sharing, etc.

My main system has 64GB of RAM and a relatively recent/powerful 12th gen core i9 processor, so it should be plenty powerful to run a basic VM that shares its bandwidth.

### More Info/Issues/Questions

- I don't understand why the fast, stable connection on L0 is not passed through to L2
- I don't really know how to go about diagnosing where the "real" problem exists
- I've tried increasing memory/processing resources to L1, but it doesn't help
- I can't help but think there are network settings on either L0 or L1 that would fix it, but I don't know enough "advanced" networking to know what settings to tweak
- Is this a compatibility issue between Oracle VirtualBox and VMWare? Does VMWare offer a free product similar to VirtualBox on which I can setup a local Windows VM?
- Could it be something about how my customer has their VPN setup? I don't really know which questions to ask their tech support to resolve the issue

Many thanks for any ideas/input you may have!!!

[image: network diagram]

Comment: I don't know for sure because I do not use Horizon (I have VMware workstation).  Make sure the guest machine has a bridged connection to the host router.